# Lighthouse error on Google PageSpeed Insights - ERRORED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST

Tags: pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I get the following error when running my site through Google PageSpeed Insights. But I don't have any issue loading the site in a browser or when running through Lighthouse in Google Chrome.

PageSpeed is light on the details and or actually providing any information.

This is an issue because my ads are not being served because of the same error being shown.

Searched a lot on Google and stack and I am unable to get any additional information on why this may be showing.

`Lighthouse returned error: ERRORED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST. Lighthouse was unable to reliably load the page you requested. Make sure you are testing the correct URL and that the server is properly responding to all requests. (Status code: 500)`

Answer (score 1):

**Please check your authorization**
You can probably see it because you're an authorized user, but the API which is loading it away from your machine is not.

Comment: There is no mention of an error 403 in the question